# Is it possible to see if DisputedLowQuality mod flag already declined?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37954492/5277820) was in the [Low Quality Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13398411). The review was completed with 4 "Recommend Deletion" and 3 "Looks OK".

As I can read in [Let's get rid of the 10K flag queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue):

> 3. Task accumulates EffectiveReviewsRequired "Looks Good" reviews.
>      Outcome: if the number of (Recommend)Delete reviews is >= the number of Looks Good reviews, mark flags "disputed" and raise DisputedLowQuality mod flag. Otherwise, mark flags "declined".

the DisputedLowQuality mod flag should be raised.

After four days I flagged the answer as NAA (my fault), because I thought it matches [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer):

> Asking for clarifications

My flag was declined by moderator.

My question is: Do I have any chance to see, if a DisputedLowQuality mod flag is already declined, so I know, that a NAA flag would be declined, too?

Comment: Those flags go directly to the mod queue and are only viewable by mods. It wouldn't help anyway as they're not handled like normal flags where they're marked helpful or declined, since it's informational stuff by the system, we tend to mark them helpful once we've looked regardless of the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon points out in his comment, the "disputed low quality review" flags are auto-generated by the system in response to certain circumstances:

- A user undeletes a post that was deleted via review
- An upvoted post receives unanimous delete votes
- A post receives more delete votes than "looks good"

These flags do not impact any flag counts for users, so you wouldn't see them in any way. I should point out that the last category of these flags has been almost pure noise, and SE has already increased the threshold once to remove many of these from review. I personally think that whole category could go away and just leave the other two and we wouldn't lose any information.

In your case, this wouldn't even matter, since your flag was directly declined by a moderator and was not judged in review. An earlier "not an answer" flag by another person was what triggered that review, which disputed their flag, but that review was not contentious enough to trigger an automatic system flag.

A moderator did see your flag, judge the post, and decide that "not an answer" didn't apply there, so there's no more action to be taken.

Comment: Could you say, what *but that review was not contentious enough to trigger an automatic system flag.* means? What's the rule?

Comment: @dur - Not sure what it's been adjusted to now, but I think it requires twice as many "Recommend Deletion" votes as "Looks Good". Again, these are pretty worthless flags, and tend to carry little information. The posts almost always aren't worthy of deletion, and at best they point to a few misguided reviewers. Not a lot that's actionable in these, which is why I think this flag subtype should probably be removed.